# Hide a div at the end of countdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, hide, countdown

This is a countdown script and it is working properly. I want to hide #mydiv at the end of countdown. Could you please help me to do this.

Thank you all

```
<div data-countdown="2015/02/28 02:18:26"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $('[data-countdown]').each(function() {
   var $this = $(this), finalDate = $(this).data('countdown');
   $this.countdown(finalDate, function(event) {     
   $this.html(event.strftime('%D gün %H:%M:%S'));
   });
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
 $('[data-countdown]').each(function() {
   var $this = $(this), finalDate = $(this).data('countdown');
   $this.countdown(finalDate, function(event) {     
   $this.html(event.strftime('%D gün %H:%M:%S'));
   $this.countdown(finalDate)
    .on('update.countdown', function(event) { $this.html(event.strftime('%D gün %H:%M:%S')); })
    .on('finish.countdown', function() { $('#selim').hide(); });
   });
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Got the syntax from the github documentation page:

```
$this.countdown(finalDate)
    .on('update.countdown', function(event) { $this.html(event.strftime('%D gün %H:%M:%S')); })
    .on('finish.countdown', function() { $('#mydiv').hide(); });
```

http://api.jquery.com/hide/

http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/documentation.html

EDIT:
Just noticed the documentation says:

> Be aware thtat ALL events should be registered with the namespace
>   *.countdown

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>jQuery countdown test</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.rawgit.com/hilios/jQuery.countdown/2.0.4/dist/jquery.countdown.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="divCountdown">test</div>

    <div id="mydiv">
        this div will be hidden in 10 seconds...
    </div>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var nowPlus30Seconds = moment().add('10', 'seconds').format('YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss');

            $('#divCountdown').countdown(nowPlus30Seconds)
                              .on('update.countdown', function (event) { $(this).html(event.strftime('%D gün %H:%M:%S')); })
                              .on('finish.countdown', function () { $('#mydiv').hide(); });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer. I am not good on jQuery. Honestly I am a html+css designer. I used the following lines but I cant make it work.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
 $('[data-countdown]').each(function() {
   var $this = $(this), finalDate = $(this).data('countdown');
   $this.countdown(finalDate, function(event) {     
   $this.html(event.strftime('%D gün %H:%M:%S'));
   $this.countdown(finalDate)
    .on('update.countdown', function(event) { $this.html(event.strftime('%D gün %H:%M:%S')); })
    .on('finish.countdown', function() { $('#selim').hide(); });
   });
 });
</script>

Comment: @Selim - I've provided a full example, you can copy all that HTML/JS into a text file and open it in a browser.  Hard to say why your code isn't working without all the HTML/JS - probably easiest to copy all my stuff and work from that.

Answer (score 0):

You can done using this simple javascript and jquery

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
var nowPlus30Seconds = moment().add('10', 'seconds').format('YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss');

$('.count1').countdown(nowPlus30Seconds)
.on('update.countdown', function (event) { $(this).html(event.strftime('%Y : %D : %H : %M : %S')); })
.on('finish.countdown', function () { $('#exp_div').hide(); });
});
</script>
```

The full code and demo [**Here**](http://www.sanwebcorner.com/2017/07/hide-div-after-countdown-expired-using.html)